# Opening dialogs in WPF MVVM

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, user-interface, mvvm

I have started learning MVVM for a project I'm writing, and I'm sketching out some of the more complicated parts of the project beforehand to help me get a better handle on how MVVM works. One of the biggest things I'm having trouble with though is dialogs, specifically custom dialogs and message boxes. Right now, I have a list of objects, and to add a new one, a button is pressed. This button calls a command in my ViewModel which invokes a Func that returns the object I want (Pile), then adds that to the list.
Here's that function

```cs
private void OnAdd()
{
    Pile? pile = GetPileToAdd?.Invoke();
    if (pile is null) return;
    Piles.Add(pile);
}
```

This function is set in the view when the data context gets set (I'm implementing a Model-First architecture)

```cs
private void PileScreenView_DataContextChanged(object sender, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.NewValue is PileScreenViewModel psvm)
    {
        psvm.GetPileToAdd = () =>
        {
            MessageBox.Show("getting pile");
            return new Pile() { Name = "Name", Length = 0 };
        };
    }
}
```

The Messagebox.Show call will eventually get replaced with a custom dialog that will provide the data needed. My question then is:

Is this MVVM compliant? It feels a bit gross having to wait until the DataContext is changed to add the method to it, but I'm 99% sure that having the messagebox call in the ViewModel is a big no-no. Also not sure if I'm allowed to interact with the Model like this from the View.

Thanks for the help and for helping me with my MVVM journey :)

Comment: Do you need to access the view to be able to show the dialog? I mean, here with `MessageBox` you definitely don't, but will your eventual custom dialog depend on your `PileScreenView` view?

Comment: It shouldn't need to reference anything in the View, no. My dialogs would only ever need to access data from the ViewModel to set things like initial values etc.

Comment: *"Also not sure if I'm allowed to interact with the Model like this from the View"* - To make it clear: the MVVM dependencies are explicitly defined as **View --> View Model --> Model**. From this simple graph it becomes obvious that only the View Model is allowed to interact with the Model. Since the interaction is defined as unidirectional, the Model is not allowed to interact with the View Model. We must honor the direction of the dependency arrows.

Comment: Another way. https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/31416.wpf-mvvm-friendly-user-notification.aspx#UserInput

Answer (score 2):

Your gut feeling is absolutely right: dialogs are components of the *View* as they interact with the user as part of the UI. Therefore, dialogs of any kind must be handled in the *View*.

Your current problem is that your *View* class `PileScreenView` depends on a particular *View Model* instance in order to register the callback.
Note that the callback itself violates *MVVM* as it delegates dialog handling to the *View Model*. The *View Model* must never execute or actively participate in any UI logic.

You can improve your design by making the dependency on the `DataContext` anonymous and independent (of the particular instance). This will also eliminate the need to observe `DataContext` changes.

Then move the dialog trigger to the *View*. Simply let the `PileScreenView` expose an "Add New Pile" button to the user.
This button will trigger the `PileScreenView` to show the dialog. Ideally, you would create a dedicated dialog view model class, that will hold the input data of the dialog.
Then use the dialog result (e.g., the dialog view model) and call e.g. `CreatePile` method on the `PileScreenViewModel` in order to pass the dialog result to the *View Model*.
The *View Model* can then create the actual `Pile` from the dialog view model class.

It's best if the *View* only knows *View Model* types by their interface:
**IPileScreenViewModel.cs**

```cs
interface IPileScreenViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
  // Create the Pile in the View Model.
  // View Model should never wait for anything. 
  // It is invoked by the View after the required data is collected.
  void CreatePile(CreatePileViewDialogModel newPileInfo);
}
```

Then in the *View* you can show the dialog e.g. on click of a corresponding button. Dialogs an their logic should be generally designed to be triggered by the UI i.e. the user:

**PileScreenView.xaml.cs**

```cs
partial class PileScreenView : UserControl
{
  private void OnCreatePileButtonClicked(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
  {
    var dialogViewModel = new CreatePileViewDialogModel();
    var createPileDialog = new CreatePileDialog() { DataContext = dialogViewModel };
    createPileDialog.ShowDialog();
   
    (this.DataContext as IPileScreenViewModel)?.CreatePile(dialogViewModel);
  }
}
```

The above example is a very simple to demonstrate how the interaction and data flow could look like. There are the usual options to send the data to the *View Model*, like data binding.
For example, `PileScreenView` could expose a dependency property e.g., `CreatedPileScreenInfo`. The `PileScreenView` would then assign the dialog result to this property, to which the `PileScreenViewModel` can bind to. This way the `DataContext` is completely unimportant for the `PileScreenView`.

**Very important note**: your current event handler introduces a potential memory leak. Since you are registering a lambda expression as event callback, you will not be able to unregister the handler. There is a chance that the garbage collector won't be able to collect the `PileScreenView` instance. The old `PileScreenViewModel` can keep it alive. You must therefore always take care to unregister event handlers. This should be your general practice to help you to guard against accidental leaks of this kind:

```cs
private void PileScreenView_DataContextChanged(object sender, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
{
  // Unregister handler from old view model instance
  if (e.oldValue is PileScreenViewModel oldPsvm)
  {
    oldPsvm.GetPileToAdd -= OnGetPileToAdd; 
  }

  if (e.NewValue is PileScreenViewModel newPsvm)
  {
    newPsvm.GetPileToAdd += OnGetPileToAdd; 
  }
}

private void OnGetPileToAdd(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  // TODO::Handle view model event
}
```

Comment: "It's best if the View only knows View Model types by their interface" and also the view is responsible for creating the dialog view model instance by its concrete type?

Comment: In your case, yes. There exists creational design patterns like Abstract Factory, to decouple the dependencies to concrete types. You can also use an IoC container to create the instances and manage their lifetime. It really depends on the importance of decoupling and extensibility. It's generally a good practice to implement code according to the SOLID principle, which suggest to code against interfaces and abstractions rather than against concrete types.

Comment: I was just trying to highlight that the view can communicate to a completely anonymous view model class, to show that watching the DataContext is redundant.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest implementing a dialog service and injecting it into the view-model.

```cs
interface IDialogService
{
    Pile? ShowPileDialog(/* any arguments that will be needed to show the dialog */);
}

class MessageBoxDialogService : IDialogService
{
    public Pile? ShowPileDialog(/* arguments */)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("getting pile");
        return new Pile() { Name = "Name", Length = 0 };      
    }
}
```

You need to register `MessageBoxDialogService` as the implementation of `IDialogService` in your DI container.

In the view-model:

```cs
class PileScreenViewModel
{
    private IDialogService _dialogService;

    public PileScriptViewModel(IDialogService dialogService)
    {
        _dialogService = dialogService;
    }

    private void OnAdd()
    {
        Pile? pile = _dialogService.GetPile(/* pass parameters from the view model */);
        if (pile is null) return;
        Piles.Add(pile);
    }      
}
```

It doesn't go against the principles of MVVM. As the view-model is decoupled from the view. You can inject a fake dialog service to test the view-model in isolation. By doing so, your code will also respect [the open-closed principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Open%E2%80%93closed_principle), i.e., if the day comes and you decide to implement your custom dialog you only need to create a new dialog service class without needing to change existing classes.

Comment: I've seen implementations like this before that never made sense to me, but this seems great! I can implement something for each type of dialog I'm going to have and re-use them. Would I simply pass in the dialog service whenever the window is created? Right now I have my MainWindowViewModel handling the creation of new ViewModels, so would the proper way to implement be to create an object in there and pass it along to each constructor as I create them?

Comment: @Hamhub7 Yes, you can do that if you want to. But you better leave the composition of your view-models to a proper dependency injection container.